# Why RS(255,233) has 32 redundant symbols?

Tags: error-correction, reed-solomon

How does Reed Solomon code(255,233) is formed?

I understand how RS(255,223) is formed because 
n=2^8-1=255
r=32, k=n-r=223

but how about RS(255,233)?
I read somewhere on the internet, it says RS(255,233) has 32 redundant symbols but why? Isn't it supposed to be 22 redundant symbols?

Any link that I can refer to would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It was a mistake. RS(255,233) would be 22 parity symbols, RS(255,223) would be 32 parity symbols.

https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~guyb/realworld/reedsolomon/reed_solomon_codes.html

Note, in some cases of RS(n,k), n-k is an odd number, so 2t+1 parity symbols.

Another note, in the Wiki article, t means the number of parity symbols, instead of the number of errors that can be corrected:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reed%E2%80%93Solomon_error_correction

The Wiki article also covers the original view for RS code, which is actually a different code with the same name. In this case, for GF(2^8), the max value for n is 256 instead of 255. Some erasure only codes use original view encoding, called "Vandermonde" encoding. Another encoding method is "Cauchy".

Comment: "Reed-Solomon codes are actually defined as polynomials that operate over finite fields, but they work in a similar manner. For m bit symbols, the codewords are 2m−1 symbols long. A popular choice is to make m = 8 so that symbols are bytes. A codeword is then 255 bytes long. The (255, 233) code is widely used; it adds 32 redundant symbols to 233 data symbols. " Does parity symbol and redundant symbol the same? I'm currently reading a book called Computer Networks, by Andrew S. Tanenbaum and in page 208 it says "it adds 32 redundant symbol to 233 data symbols". Please enlighten me on this.

Comment: @NurinIzzatiJafri - the 233 is a typo and should be 223 (it's a mistake in the book). Parity and redundant are essentially the same as used in that text. Original view Reed Solomon is mostly used for erasure only cases, and codeword size for GF(2^8) can be 256 bytes, versus BCH view where the max is 255 bytes. Also Reed Solomon doesn't have to be based on binary field. The Wiki examples use GF(929) (929 is a prime number).